# Debugging dynamically loaded JavaScript generated by Typescript

Tags: javascript, debugging, typescript

I am writing a SPA application with JavaScript files generated with typescript. When I put a break point in typescript code and start debugging the application, if the JavaScript was loaded with the main page, the debugging works perfectly and the execution stops in my typescript code. But if the part of the view is loaded with Ajax (for example with $.get jQuery command), and  that partial view contains a reference to JavaScript file, the loaded code gets executed, but the breakpoint is not hit.

I am using Typescript 1.4, Internet Explorer 11,  VS Ultimate 2013 with Update 4 and WebEssentials 2013 ver 2.5.3

I created a simplest test application do check if something else in my code could cause this behaviour, but I still got the same result (I can share the code if required)

Is there any way to debug the dynamically loaded js files (putting 'debugger' in the code stops the execution, but I would like to be able to do it from VS and to break in typescript code, not js)?

Comment: Does the dynamically loaded JavaScript file have a Sourcemap reference to the TypeScript file?  If so, is the .js.map file available?  Are you seeing any 404s if you enable tracing on the network tab?  Does it work if you put the breakpoint in the generated .js file (not the .ts file) that is being dynamically loaded?

Comment: Yes, there is a source map reference to ts file. With default settings, when dynamically loading js, the map file cannot be found (the path is wrong although when including script reference in main page browser knows where to look for map file). I changed the root directory for source map and now browser knows where to find map file but still skips the breakpoint. It doesn't work even when i put the breakpoint directly in js file.

Comment: Have you tried generating the source maps inline?  I have found that this can work around folder issues